# SQL How to SELECT specific fields from tables using a table of table names

Tags: sql-server, database

SO,

I am trying to find a (messy?) solution to an even more messy problem. I have a SQL Server 2014 database which, in part, stores data from another software package but also stores data for me. The software creates a table with specific fields for each set of data - a `Name` and a `Geometry` field. For example, one might contain cities (`dtCitiesData`), another contains roads (`dtRoadsData`), another contains states(`dtStates`), etc. I also have a table (`dtSpatialDataTables`) which stores the names of the tables which store the data I want. That table only has 2 fields: `ID` and `TableName`.

I would like to create a SELECT statement which queries `dtSpatialDataTables` for all entries, then queries all tables with the name corresponding to each `TableName` result, and SELECTs `Name` and `Geometry` from them.

In pseudocode, effectively I want to do this:

```
SELECT TableName FROM dtSpatialDataTables

FOREACH TableName :
    SELECT Name, Geometry FROM (TableName)
```

I can do this easily PHP via a first query against `dtSpatialDataTables` and then a loop of queries to each of the returned row `TableName`s but I want to know if this is possible via SQL directly.

In reality, what I want to do is create a VIEW with this query so I can directly query the VIEW rather than soak of processing time on potentially lots of queries.

Is this possible? Unfortunately, my Google-ing doesn't turn up any meaningful results.

Thanks everyone!

PS: I figure this is messy and not the way this should be done. But I have no choice in how the software puts data in my database. I simply have to use what I get. So... whether this is the "right" way or the "wrong" way, I need a solution. :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you want, but it sounds that you could create dynamic SQL and run it with exec. That's not something you can do in a view, but maybe a stored procedure would be ok?

Comment: sounds like you need a dynamic sql or cursor (choose your poison) but you will need to create a procedure since neither will work in a VIEW

Comment: You also need to specify if you want `Name, Geometry` to be DISTINCT or not

Comment: You could build a dynamic SQL query. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955625/dynamic-query-to-union-multiple-databases

Comment: The idea for doing this would be to a) save on processing time and b) make it easy to access the data with a single PHP query. A view works well for those, but would a stored procedure be fast? Or is that just doing what PHP would do in a loop?

Comment: The clean way to do this is to consolidate all your spatial data into one table and normalize it with relationships to the tables it used to be in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this using dynamic sql..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_SpatialData_GetByID
(
    @ID INT
)   
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @Selects NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT Name, Geometry, ''<<TableName>>'' AS Source FROM <<TableName>>'

    SELECT  @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL + ' UNION ALL ', '') + REPLACE(@Selects, '<<TableName>>', TableName)
    FROM    dtSpatialDataTables
    WHERE   ID = @ID

    EXEC(@SQL)
END
GO
```

I feel like you left out filtering of the Geometry tables somewhere so you might have to add a filter to the `@Selects` statement

Comment: Perfect! Some slight modifications and this worked like a charm. Thanks!