# Iterate through a list of database names and run a query on the same table in each database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm working with a server that creates a database every month with the same tables. The only thing that changes is the database name. I can use this query to create a table of the database names.

```
Select name 
into DB_List
FROM master.sys.databases
where name Like '%DB%' and create_date > '2020-01-01'
```

Which returns:

```
DB013120,
DB022920,
DB033120,
etc.
```

I need to grab the different database names and input them into another query like the one below.

```
SELECT *
  FROM [DB******].[dbo].[Table]
```

I know that I can use UNION but the problem is that the stored procedure will have to be manually updated every time there is a new database added. Currently running on SQL SERVER 2016

Comment: Aside from the fact that in most cases that is a terrible design.

Comment: @DaleK None of the solutions seemed to work for me because of the whole monthly database creation problem.

Comment: What solutions did you try? If "none of the solutions worked" then I suspect you didn't try enough or the right ones, because this has definitely been solved before - I have at least 20 answers like this on this site alone. First please specify your version of SQL Server.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17955771/61305) is also pretty similar - it even has the same database name wildcard pattern!

Comment: The questions I was getting involved iterating through lists of strings or cursors but your solution should work for my use case. Thank you @DaleK

Answer (score 0):

You can just build the `UNION` dynamically. For SQL Server 2017+:

```
DECLARE @sql  nvarchar(max),
        @base nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT *
               FROM $db$.dbo.[Table]';

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG
  (REPLACE(@base, N'$db$', QUOTENAME(name)),
   ' UNION ALL ')
FROM master.sys.databases
WHERE name LIKE N'%DB%' 
  AND create_date > '20200101';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

If you're using an older version (please always state that up front), you could use `FOR XML PATH`, which is a little messier and requires some whitespace-sensitive cleanup:

```
DECLARE @sql  nvarchar(max),
        @base nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT *
               FROM $db$.dbo.[Table]';

SELECT @sql = STUFF((SELECT N' UNION ALL
' + REPLACE(@base, N'$db$', QUOTENAME(name))
   FROM master.sys.databases
   WHERE name LIKE N'%DB%' 
     AND create_date > '20200101'
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,10, '');

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Its currently on SQL SERVER 2016 Version 13.0.5026 so I can't use STRING_AGG