# Automating Power BI Queries Across Multiple SQL Server Databases with Identical Schemas

Tags: sql-server, database, powerbi, reporting

I have a question regarding the best way to connect to all databases on a dedicated server with the same database schema in a PowerBI application.

Let me explain: I am developing software, and the backend part is the same for all my clients. However, each client has their own database (with an identical database schema). All databases are stored on the same dedicated server. My goal is to perform reporting with Power BI by executing the same queries across all databases on the server. However, I am struggling to find a way to execute the same query on all databases on the server without specifying the database name. I would like to avoid having to specify the name of each database, as this needs to be automated, given that there are around a hundred databases on the server.

I have searched online but haven't found documentation that seems to fit my needs. Since I am a beginner with Power BI, I'm turning to the community to get some guidance.

I am using SQL Server 2016/2019.

Thanks for your help!

I attempted to create a dynamic connection in Power BI to fetch data from multiple SQL Server databases sharing an identical schema on a dedicated server. My expectation was to automate the process, eliminating the need to specify each database manually.

To achieve this, I explored various Power BI documentation. But unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution that precisely fit my requirements. I experimented with different connection configurations and explored Power BI functionalities related to database connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to do this in SQL with Views that `UNION ALL` across all the databases. Then in Power BI you are only making the one query to that View.

Comment: This is the easiest and cleanest solution.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!
Small additional questions:
- Where would you save the SQL view given that it is "general" to all tables?
- Is it possible to run an SQL view without specifying the names of the various databases?

Comment: Personally, I would create a new database, and in this new database, I would create the Views. Then in turn Power BI (or any other) will connect to this one database. In terms of creating the views, you could write these manually, depending how many databases & tables you have, or you can do it with dynamic SQL. See second option in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955625/dynamic-query-to-union-multiple-databases

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did a test and the solution does indeed simplify things. 
Now, let's imagine that I have 4 dedicated servers with +- 100 databases hosted on them (same structure). How would you go about avoiding as much duplication as possible in the queries made to retrieve the data in Power BI? I imagine that this scenario is more complicated.
Thanks again for your advice.

Comment: Please help Accept above answer for the benefit of all.

Comment: I would follow the same approach and have the `UNION ALL` views on a dedicated DB per instance, hopefully via dynamic SQL. Then pick one of the instances, and set-up [linked servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN) to the other three. Then again, create a set of `UNION ALL` views to bring it all together using the fully qualified names of the linked server views `LinkName.DatabaseName.SchemaName(dbo).ViewName`.